# android 8.0 user-defined view Application Crash

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

When I use my application in Android 8.0, it crashes. Here is the log:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.**.**.XListView
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.****
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Can't find class com.****. installed bundles
```

The *** was hidden by me.

`XListView` is a user-defined view that extends `ListView`.
But when I use the application on a lower version, like Android 7.1, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0... it works normally.

What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: check XListView support